# Function $f(x,y)$ analytic with respect to both $x$ and $y$, is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)$ analytic with respect to $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, analytic-functions

Assume $U$ is some open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f: U \times U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for a fixed $y$ $$x \mapsto f(x,y)$$ is analytic, and for a fixed $x$ $$y \mapsto f(x,y)$$ is analytic. Is it true that for a fixed $y$ $$x \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)$$ is also analytic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See edit before reading.

The answer is yes but requires some work. If $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is analytic for any fixed $y \in U$ and $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is analytic for any fixed $x\in U$ then by Hartogs' Theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_theorem

$f(x,y)$ is analytic in the 2-variable sense, i.e. it admits a power series expansion in 2 variables for $(x,y) \in U  \times U$. In particular, you can differentiate this power series with respect to $y$ and obtain a power series expansion for $x \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)$ for $x \in U$. Hence your desired map is analytic.

---

Edit: I misread the question thinking that $U$ was a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The answer to the question is in fact no and a counter example can be found in the link to the Wikipedia article above.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to use Hartogs Theorem in this setting? The link you provided specifically says there is no analogue in real numbers for it, how do we get real analyticity on $U \times U$ ?

Comment: Ahh sorry I misread your question and thought that $U \subset \mathbb{C}$. The link should hopefully answer your question though :)

Comment: Yeah that's what i suspected :P The link you provided has the answer either way, so here you go